# excel-2007 zoom in zoom out

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, vba

hi is it possible to write something like zoom-in and zoom-out button...

for example i will have a userform on which i will have two buttons one for each zoom in and out... whenever the user clicks on one of the buttons plus user clicks the cells (or selects the range) that cell or range will be increased or decreased using the ActiveWindow.Zoom option....

if this is possible plz can you tell me how? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try ActiveWindow.Zoom = 50 within your VBA. That will set your zoom to 50%.